# Is it possible to use SLIM with ReactJs both together

Tags: reactjs, slim-lang

There is a classic React component:

```jsx
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Is it possible to use Slim instead of HTML? Something like this:

```jsx
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      form.commentForm
        input type="text" placeholder="Your name"
        input type="text" placeholder="Say something..."
        input type="submit" value="Post"
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: There isn't a way to do this now.

Comment: In that *classic* example, that is **not** HTML.  It is JSX. JSX compiles to JavaScript commands that run against the virtual DOM.  ASAIK, this is the only markup available at the moment.

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't know that is not HTML

Comment: If React.js source code is hackable enough then one could, hypothetically, add any kind of language replacing JSX. When React will become a de-facto standard on the web (!) we will see more and more template languages supported (dreaming).

Comment: That's one of reasons people not using ReactJS.  JSX force you write raw html instead your favorite template language.  Take a look of how react- Jade handle this https://github.com/pugjs/react-jade.  Slim could be done in similar way.